# react-native run-android error metro server

Tags: react-native

I'm doing a react-native app.

When I launch my app with react-native start or npm run start and react-native run-android, it install on my phone the app but don't launch it automatically and when I launch it by myself, I have this error :

[image: error]

Can you help me I don't know what is my problem ?

thank

Comment: Please include the text of the error than images.

Comment: Hi, this is my error on my phone : "Unable to load script.Make sure you are either running a Metro server or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release"

Answer (score 0):

I think your phone and your computer are not connected to the same network

Comment: Hello, I think I'm alright about the network but I forgot to add I launch my app only with a cable between my computer and my phone. I don't launch it without it